# Symfony body form-data null in a POST request

Tags: php, rest, symfony, web, postman

Lately I've been trying to make a Symfony application but I've had issues for making a POST request with a Body.

[The postman request looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCF5V.png)

i used the **form-data** option for it

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/user", name="addUser", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function addUser(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $this->logger->info("hi");
        $this->logger->info(json_encode($request));
        $username = $data["username"];
        $password = $data["password"];
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Expecting mandatory parameters!');
        }

        $this->accountRepository->saveAccount($username, $password );

        $response = new JsonResponse(['status' => 'Account created!'], 201);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

But the $request varirable is empty

> {"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}

[And obviously the code runs into an error due to that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS6vE.png)

Comment: And what does your post looks like? Can you provide a curl example of that post request?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `json_decode` there? From your postman screenshot, it does not look like you were sending JSON in the first place.

Comment: I've been using to get the content from the Request using `json_decode`
maybe it wan't the best solution
as for the curl request the best i can provide is this:https://gyazo.com/5bd722aa0dbf5622b7f587b8e96c6c8e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send JSON, don't use `formData` but raw mode with `Content-type: application/json header`.

If you need to use `formData`, use a Symfony form for use `$form->handleRequest($request)`

Comment: Thank you a lot! 
i used raw with JSON and it worked 
i remember using formData for it last time i used symfony